# CKEditor Removes IFrame

Tags: c#, html, iframe, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I try to load value from the database into a field that is editable by CKEditor, it strips out the iframe tag from it.

For Example, I send the following html to the be printed out on the screen:

```
<div class="videodetector">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eSYKJ8WQ508?autohide=1&controls=1&showinfo=0" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

But when I look at the printed out html, I see something like this:

```
<div class="videodetector"><img class="cke_iframe" data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FeSYKJ8WQ508%3Fautohide%3D1%26amp%3Bcontrols%3D1%26amp%3Bshowinfo%3D0%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E" data-cke-real-node-type="1" alt="IFrame" title="IFrame" align="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" data-cke-resizable="true"></div>
```

It seems to inject this image tag where the iframe is suppose to go.

I have researched this online and I tried adding the following code to the config.js, but it does not make a difference for me:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe(*)';
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Note: If I print this out in a div that is not editable by CKEditor, then the iframe loads without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
 var CKEIframes = $('.cke_iframe');
 var CKEIframesL = CKEIframes.length;
 for (i = 0; i <CKEIframesL; i ++ ) {
  $(CKEIframes[i]).replaceWith(decodeURIComponent($(CKEIframes[i]).data('cke-realelement')));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to add many HTML tags into my text, including iframe. So I use these settings and they work fine:

```
'extraAllowedContent'=>'*(*)',
'allowedContent'=>true
```